# Rails api POST testing is not allowing me to access json object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I've spent a long time trying to figure out where this POST behavior for my Users controller is messing up, and I'm out of ideas.

I've been getting the error back from the binding pry after typing json in the command line:

`{"message"=>"Couldn't find User without an ID"}`

Which is odd, since i'm simply creating a new user. The controller `user_params` matches the `valid_attribute` payload I created in the test env.

Removing the `binding.pry` I receive this error:

```
 1) Users API POST /users when the request is valid creates a user
     Failure/Error: expect(json['username']).to eq('Tychus')

       expected: "Tychus"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

My initial GET tests appeared to be working, so I'm not sure why my POSTs are going so awry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**spec/requests/users_spec.rb**

```
  # Test suite for POST /users
  describe 'POST /users' do
    # valid payload
    let(:valid_attributes) { { username: 'Tychus', password: 'password1' } }

    context 'when the request is valid' do
      before { post '/users', params: valid_attributes }

      it 'creates a user' do
        binding.pry
        expect(json['username']).to eq('Tychus')
        expect(json['password']).to eq('password1')
      end

      xit 'returns a status code of 201' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end
    end
  end
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :create, :destroy]

  # GET /users/:id
  def show
    json_response(@user)
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    binding.pry
    json_response(@user, :created)
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.permit(:username, :password)
  end

  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the `set_user` private method, it was trying to look for an `id`. Removing `:create` from the `before_action` fixed this issue.